# Determine if left or right side of ImageView was clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have a `RecyclerView`, and as an item, among other things, there's a `SimpleDraweeView`. I would like to determine if the user clicked the left or the right part of the `SimpleDraweeView` and then do stuff accordingly. I've tried setting up `onTouchListener` but it gets called multiple times instead of once, and also if I scroll withing the `RecyclerView` it gets called again.

```
holder.getDoubleImageBinding().ivImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getX() < holder.getDoubleImageBinding().ivImage.getWidth() / 2) {
                mListener.onClickLeft();
            } else {
                mListener.onClickRight();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I've also tried getting the width and `X` and setting `onClickListener`, but `X` is always 0.0.

```
holder.getDoubleImageBinding().ivImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            imageWidth = holder.getDoubleImageBinding().ivImage.getWidth() / 2;
            imageX = holder.getDoubleImageBinding().ivImage.getX();
            holder.getDoubleImageBinding().ivImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.getDoubleImageBinding().ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (imageWidth > imageX) {
                mListener.onClickLeft();
            } else {
                mListener.onClickRight();
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

In the end, I decided to add 2 buttons behind the `ImageView`

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="299dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ap_circle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/ap_placeholder"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="299dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_image"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="299dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn_left"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_image"/>
```

Comment: I believe you should get the onTouchEvent ?

Comment: As I said, I have tried `onTouchEvent` but it gets fired for each item of the list in `RecyclerView` and also when I scroll, it gets fired again.

Answer (score 1):

If your ImageView has an absolute size then you could do something like this:

```
            <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_wallpaper"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Normally a **FrameLayout** should have only one child. However if you give it two children like I did above, **the second child will overlap the first one**. By doing this, the **ViewHolder** implementation should look similar to this one:

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mIvWallpaper;
    private View mVLeft;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mVLeft = itemView.findViewById(R.id.left);
        mIvWallpaper = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_wallpaper);

        mVLeft.setOnClickListener(this);
        mIvWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        if (id == R.id.left) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Left side was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.iv_wallpaper) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Right side was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Since the **View** is on top of the **ImageView** (remember: declared second in the layout) it will get the onClick event first. Sadly this method only works if you are using a fixed size **ImageView**. I can't think of any fast and easy way if you have a variable size. You would probably have to workaround with **LinearLayout** and the weight attribute, but I haven't managed it to overlap Views with it.

Hopefully I could help you though!

Edit: If the **ImageView** has a variable size you could use the same method. This is probably bad practice but you could initialize your **FrameLayout** and then after initialization of the **ImageView** add a child **View** to your **FrameLayout** with the height of your **ImageView** and half the width of it. Then just set the onClickListener and you should have your desired result as described above (have not tried it, just thought of it now).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but my `imageView` is in a `ConstraintsLayout`. But your solution seems a bit hacky. In the end, what I've done is place two transparent buttons behind the `imageView`.

Comment: Yeah it definitey isn't the cleanest solution. Thanks for telling me your solution maybe I'll need it in the future!

Comment: I will post it as an `Edit`. Cheers!